# Equivalent objective C from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I'm following a documentation on braintree for IOS.

It recommends to implement a method like this (in swift):

```
func onLookupComplete(_ request: BTThreeDSecureRequest, result: BTThreeDSecureLookup, next: @escaping () -> Void) {
  // Optionally inspect the lookup result and prepare UI if a challenge is required
  next()
}
```

My target code is some objective C for react native module where function are defined like this :

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getAddressLine1: (NSString *) address 
  callback: (RCTResponseSenderBlock) callback)
{ ... }
```

What would be the equivalent of the swift implementation for the objective C module (especially the "next: @escaping" part) ?

Note: here is the [braintree doc](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/migration/ios/v4)

Thank you

Comment: `next: @escaping () -> Void)`: ` @escaping () -> Void`: That's an escaping closure, treat it as an Objective-C block, it's called Block in Objective-C

Comment: Can be seen : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present (except it's nullable, so there is no need for `@escaping` and in Objective-C: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller?language=objc

Comment: Here's another exact as yours: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate & https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animatewithduration?language=objc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next: @escaping () -> Void`

So `() -> Void`, that's called a closure, and in Objective-C, it's called a Block.

`@escaping` means that the method will "end" before the closure is called.
In other words, if you have `func myMethod(escaped: @escaping () -> Void) -> Bool`, and if you write

```
let methodOutput = myMethod(escaped: { 
    print("here closure has been called")
}
print(methodOutput)
```

`print(methodOutput)` has strong chances (but not necessarily) to be printed before `print("here closure has been called")`. Usually because it's async.

Now, here's a sample from a `UIView` method to know how to translate them:

In [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate):

```
class func animate(
    withDuration duration: TimeInterval,
    animations: @escaping () -> Void
)
```

In [Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animatewithduration?language=objc):

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations;
```

Now, I've said that it's not mandatory for it to be asynchronously called, because we could image this scenario in pseudo code:

```
func myMethod(escaped:  @escaping () -> Void)) {
    if canBeDone == false { //In Swift, a guard is better
        escaped()
    } else {
        doLongAsyncProcess(onDidFinished: { escaped() })
    }
}
```

If `canBeDone` is false, the closure will be called directly (synchrone), but if not, it will be called later (asynchrone).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is the working result : 
- (void)onLookupComplete:(BTThreeDSecureRequest *)request
                result:(BTThreeDSecureLookup*)result
                next:(void (^)(void))next {
    next();
}